# How to sum 15 second intervals within 1 minute window in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have prometheus operator which scrapes a metric every 15 seconds:
[image]

I would like to "zoom out a bit" and show a sum of my latencies per 1 minute instead. However, I can't find a query to do so. I tried various options with `rate()` and `sum_over_time()`, but queries simply error out.

I also tried changing this option:
[image]
to 1 m. What happened is 3 out of 4 15second intervals just got omitted. Instead of summing all my 15 second results in a minute.

How could I achieve the desired result?

Comment: FYI, what is being graphed there is not a "sum of latencies" it's a "sum of requests per second, averaged over 1 minute" (45 seconds actually, but let's not go there).

Comment: That being said, your question is not very clear. What would you expect the output to be if you got e.g. 100 requests at 5 seconds intervals and each took 1 second? A line that starts at zero (before the requests start), ramps up to 12 (12 seconds spent every minute responding) and then ramps down to zero?

Comment: @AlinSînpălean in reference to your first comment. Yes, I am looking for the sum of requests per second. 45s or 1 minute either one is fine for my purposes. In reference to your second comment. I really don't care how long the requests are taking. I only care about the number of requests. So say I get 10 requests on every scrape which happens once every 15 seconds. Meaning I get 10*4=40 per minute. I want to see a datapoint on the graph that would say 40. Say, next minute I got 50 in total, great 50 is next point. I want the min step to be 1 minute, but naturally all the counts included.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you're looking for is

```
sum by(job) (increase(web_latencies_summary_count[1m]))
```

with a *Min step* of `1m`.

Unfortunately, due to the way `increase()` / `rate()` is computed by Prometheus, this will actually give you the number of requests over 45 seconds extrapolated to 1 minute (i.e. `increase[45s] / 45 * 60`). A more accurate formula would be

```
sum by(job) (increase(web_latencies_summary_count[75s])) / 75 * 60
```

but do note that (a) this depends on your scrape interval; and (b) due to the timestamps not being exactly 15 seconds apart, the results will not be integers.

Comment: So if I add a step of 1min doesn't it loose my data? Meaning if I scrape every 15 sec, and the graph shows a specific number at each 15 sec interval, when I make min step = 1m, graph seems to just throw away the points without recomputing anything. This makes me feel like the data is being lost.

Comment: The increase is computed over a range of 1 minute, every 1 minute, so no data is lost. (Except that the obvious query computes it over 45 seconds every 1 minute, so every 4th data point is thrown away. Hence the second, convoluted and fragile expression.)